# TypeError: ... is not JSON serializable error when adding new values to an object by Python

Tags: python, json, serialization

I have such a json object:

```
{
     "people":[
        {"firstName":"Hasan Sait", "lastName":"Arslan", "email":"hasan.sait.arslan@gmail.com"}]
}
```

I want to add new value to this json object by python as the following:

```
import json

with open('data.json', 'r+') as json_file:
        json_data = json.load(json_file)
        people = json_data['people']
        people.append({"firstName":"Mehmet"})
        json_file.seek(0, 0)
        json.dump(json_file, json_data)
        json_file.truncate()
```

I get the following error: `TypeError: <open file 'data.json', mode 'r+' at 0x7f3f85a4b5d0> is not JSON serializable`

In stackoverflow, there are similar questions to mine asked before, but I couldn't find any beneficial solution from them.

Could you tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: <open file 'data.json', mode 'r+' at 0x7f3f85a4b5d0>

Comment: Your `json` is not valid. `"email":"hasan.sait.arslan@gmail.com"]}` this part should be `"email":"hasan.sait.arslan@gmail.com"}]`

Comment: Thank you. The problem is not that. It is just a typing error I have done by writing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**json.dumps** doesn't write to streams, it simply takes the object and returns the JSON-serialized string. You can then save that to the file.

```
import json

with open('data.json', 'r+') as json_file:
      json_data = json.load(json_file)
      people = json_data['people']
      people.append({"firstName":"Mehmet"})
      json_file.seek(0, 0)
      jsonString = json.dumps(json_data)
      json_file.write(jsonString)
      json_file.truncate()
```

Answer (score 1):

You just got the order of json_file and json_data wrong, so it tells you that you can't use the filepointer as json. The object is first and the file pointer second when using json.dump.